# How to iterate over an array of hashes which contain instantiated object information in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration, hash-of-hashes

I created a class called Dish, where I then created a number of menu objects, items for a menu containing name and price, the information which was obtained through the initialized method. when calling

```
chickenstew = Dish.new("Chicken Stew", 4.50)
```

I then added a number of these objects to an array contained in an instance variable `@menu = []` of a new class, called Menu, using the method `def add_to_menu` and `@menu << args`. When I display the new menu array containing the individual objects, you obviously get the object information, in addition to the name and price info, as follows:

```
[[#<Dish:0x007f9662134818 @dish={:name=>"Chicken Stew", :price=>4.5}>,
  #<Dish:0x007f966206ec30 @dish={:name=>"Beef & Ale Pie", :price=>5.0}>,
  #<Dish:0x007f966101a7a8 @dish={:name=>"Chicken & Leek Pie", :price=>4.0}>,
  #<Dish:0x007f9662365420 @dish={:name=>"Vegetable Pie", :price=>3.5}>,
  #<Dish:0x007f96622de038 @dish={:name=>"Fish Pie", :price=>5.5}>,
  #<Dish:0x007f966224f068 @dish={:name=>"Chips", :price=>2.0}>,
  #<Dish:0x007f966222c1d0 @dish={:name=>"Mushy Peas", :price=>1.5}>]]
```

My question is, how on earth do you iterate through this array of hashes, in order to extract just the name and price details, in order to `puts` this to the screen? I have tried `@menu.each { |hash| puts "Item: #{hash[:name]. Price: £#{hash[:price]}" }` but this obviously fails and I get no end of errors such as **'TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer'**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have `[[..]]`, so `@menu[0].each {..` will work. What you think is `Hash`, they are actually `Dish` object, which is `AR` object.

Comment: cheers for that help, it didn't unfortunately, but that may be because I needed to called dish.name and dish.price rather than trying the code as was, but just adding the [0] to it. Cheers though!

Comment: No. the error was from `@menu.each { |hash| `, what you think here a `hash` is the inner `Array`. And on that you called `[:name]` and that throws error. So `@menu[0].each { |hash| puts "Item: #{hash[:name]. Price: £#{hash[:price]}" }` will work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a hash inside your array. This is object of Dish class, so:

```
@menu.first.each { |dish| puts "Item: #{dish.name}. Price: £#{dish.price}" }
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked perfectly, thanks for the very quick reply, you have just saved me hours of more trial and error.